# How to display forEach for an object nested inside multiple arrays and objects

Tags: node.js, express, foreach, ejs

I apologize if answers exist elsewhere, please redirect me. I'm using node.js, express, & ejs.

**server.js**

```
//API v4//media
const mediaAPI = { method: 'GET',
url: 'https://api.media.com/v4/media',  
  qs: 
   { access_token: 'abc123'
     }    
  };

//media data 
app.get('/media', function (req, res) {

  try {
    request(mediaAPI, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        const mediaphotos = JSON.parse(body);
        const mediaphotolist = mediaphotos.response.checkins.items.map(item => item );

        res.render('media.ejs', {mediaphotolist}); 
        console.log(mediaphotolist);
      });   
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("Something went wrong", e)
  }
  });
```

Based on this code, I can see the following array in my console.log(mediaphotolist). Please note, there are multiple items returned, I'm only showing one to save space.

```
[ { uid: 123456789,
    person:
     { uid: 1234,
       first_name: 'frank',
       last_name: 'doe',
       contact: [Object] },
    house:
     { hid: 5724,
       house_name: 'Peterson House',
       house_style: 'Modern' },
    neighborhood:
     { nid: 379,
       neighborhood_name: 'Dexter',
       neighborhood_type: 'Old' },
    media: { count: 1, items: [Array] }
} ]
```

There is an image URL inside of the **media: [Array]** that I want to get. As seen inside postman, it looks like this...

```
media: {
        count: 1,
        items: [
          {
            photo_id: 1234,
            photo: {
                photo_img_sm: https://media.net/photos/123_200x200.jpg,
                photo_img_md: https://media.net/photos/456_640x640.jpg,
                photo_img_lg: https://media.net/photos/789_1280x1280.jpg
                     }
                 }
              ]
        }
```

In my media.ejs file I have the following ejs code to display first_name and photo_img_sm...

**media.ejs**

```
<ul>
  <% mediaphotolist.forEach(function(photoofhouse){ %>
    <div>
      <li>
        <p>First Name: <%= photoofhouse.person.first_name %></p>
        <img src= "<%= photoofhouse.media.items.photo.photo_img_sm %>" alt="">
      </li>
    </div>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

I can make the first_name show using the ejs script seen above, but, I don't know know to dig deeper to get the photo_img_sm object that lives within these nested arrays and objects. I'm hoping I don't have to change my server side code and simply learn the proper syntax for accessing this photo_img_sm object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, `media.items` is an array. So every media may have more than one items and photos. If you want to display the first item photo you should use this code

```
<img src= "<%= photoofhouse.media.items[0].photo.photo_img_sm %>" alt="">
```

In case you have more than one items inside media and want to display them all, you have to loop the media.items array like this:

```
<% mediaphotolist.forEach(function(photoofhouse){ %>
    <div>
      <li>
        <p>First Name: <%= photoofhouse.person.first_name %></p>
        <% photoofhouse.media.items.forEach(function(el){ %>
            <img src= "<%= el.photo.photo_img_sm %>" alt="">
        <% }) %>
      </li>
    </div>
  <% }) %>
```

Comment: you rock! This worked very well, interesting so if I had more arrays further in, I would add another forEach like so`<% el.foo.items.forEach(function(bar){ %>`? (assuming the next array is also items)

Comment: yes you could do this in case your data had that schema

Answer (score 1):

I've used this as an example hope you can apply it to your scenario say you the variable is named bg 
hence

```
let bg = [ { uid: 123456789,
person:
 { uid: 1234,
   first_name: 'frank',
   last_name: 'doe',
   contact: [Object] },
house:
 { hid: 5724,
   house_name: 'Peterson House',
   house_style: 'Modern' },
neighborhood:
 { nid: 379,
   neighborhood_name: 'Dexter',
   neighborhood_type: 'Old' },
media:   {       
    items: [
      {
        photo_id: 1234,
        photo: {
            photo_img_sm: 'https://media.net/photos/123_200x200.jpg',
            photo_img_md: 'https://media.net/photos/456_640x640.jpg',
            photo_img_lg: 'https://media.net/photos/789_1280x1280.jpg'
                 }
             }
          ]
    }} ]
```

You could access the photos like this

```
bg[0].media["items"][0]["photo"]
```

or using the dot notation

```
bg[0].media["items"][0].photo
```

if there were multiple items like you said you have

```
let gb = [ { uid: 123456789,
    person:
     { uid: 1234,
       first_name: 'frank',
       last_name: 'doe',
       contact: [Object] },
    house:
     { hid: 5724,
       house_name: 'Peterson House',
       house_style: 'Modern' },
    neighborhood:
     { nid: 379,
       neighborhood_name: 'Dexter',
       neighborhood_type: 'Old' },
    media:   {       
        items: [
          {
            photo_id: 1234,
            photo: {
                photo_img_sm: 'https://media.net/photos/123_200x200.jpg',
                photo_img_md: 'https://media.net/photos/456_640x640.jpg',
                photo_img_lg: 'https://media.net/photos/789_1280x1280.jpg'
                     }
                 }
              ]
        }
} ,{ uid: 123456789,
    person:
     { uid: 1234,
       first_name: 'frank',
       last_name: 'doe',
       contact: [Object] },
    house:
     { hid: 5724,
       house_name: 'Peterson House',
       house_style: 'Modern' },
    neighborhood:
     { nid: 379,
       neighborhood_name: 'Dexter',
       neighborhood_type: 'Old' },
    media:   {       
        items: [
          {
            photo_id: 1234,
            photo: {
                photo_img_sm: 'https://media.net/photos/123_200x200.jpg',
                photo_img_md: 'https://media.net/photos/456_640x640.jpg',
                photo_img_lg: 'https://media.net/photos/789_1280x1280.jpg'
                     }
                 }
              ]
        }
},{ uid: 123456789,
    person:
     { uid: 1234,
       first_name: 'frank',
       last_name: 'doe',
       contact: [Object] },
    house:
     { hid: 5724,
       house_name: 'Peterson House',
       house_style: 'Modern' },
    neighborhood:
     { nid: 379,
       neighborhood_name: 'Dexter',
       neighborhood_type: 'Old' },
    media:   {       
        items: [
          {
            photo_id: 1234,
            photo: {
                photo_img_sm: 'https://media.net/photos/123_200x200.jpg',
                photo_img_md: 'https://media.net/photos/456_640x640.jpg',
                photo_img_lg: 'https://media.net/photos/789_1280x1280.jpg'
                     }
                 }
              ]
        }
},{ uid: 123456789,
    person:
     { uid: 1234,
       first_name: 'frank',
       last_name: 'doe',
       contact: [Object] },
    house:
     { hid: 5724,
       house_name: 'Peterson House',
       house_style: 'Modern' },
    neighborhood:
     { nid: 379,
       neighborhood_name: 'Dexter',
       neighborhood_type: 'Old' },
    media:   {       
        items: [
          {
            photo_id: 1234,
            photo: {
                photo_img_sm: 'https://media.net/photos/123_200x200.jpg',
                photo_img_md: 'https://media.net/photos/456_640x640.jpg',
                photo_img_lg: 'https://media.net/photos/789_1280x1280.jpg'
                     }
                 }
              ]
        }
},{ uid: 123456789,
    person:
     { uid: 1234,
       first_name: 'frank',
       last_name: 'doe',
       contact: [Object] },
    house:
     { hid: 5724,
       house_name: 'Peterson House',
       house_style: 'Modern' },
    neighborhood:
     { nid: 379,
       neighborhood_name: 'Dexter',
       neighborhood_type: 'Old' },
    media:   {       
        items: [
          {
            photo_id: 1234,
            photo: {
                photo_img_sm: 'https://media.net/photos/123_200x200.jpg',
                photo_img_md: 'https://media.net/photos/456_640x640.jpg',
                photo_img_lg: 'https://media.net/photos/789_1280x1280.jpg'
                     }
                 }
              ]
        }
}]
```

You could iterate through each and still access the photo variable 
like so

```
gb.forEach(onePhoto =>{ for (d in onePhoto["media"]['items'][0].photo){console.log(onePhoto["media"]['items'][0].photo[d])}})
```